# Can I add a hyperlink to an Apple app store description

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app published in the app store. Its description includes a link to a web page. However, it is not click-able, just regular text.

There is no preview option on iTunes connect (the developer console) so it's not possible to test using html in the description.

So, is it possible to use html, or some other markup to create a 'live' link in the app store?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, thanks. Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTML formatting is not allowed in the description. From the iTunes Connect Developers Guide:

> Description: A description of the app, detailing the features and functionality.
>   Limited to 4000 characters. The description should be in plain text,
>   with line breaks as needed. HTML format is not supported.

Please see the link the [App Store Documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devf29afbb74) for details.